# How to concatenate and string and escapte characters in php

Tags: php

I'm having problem concatenating and escaping string i have this in my code

```
$specModel = 'ShoeBrand';
$modelName = "\common\models\".$specModel ;
```

i would like to produce somethinglike `\common\models\ShoeBrand` and it's not working below are all my try and the output

```
"\common\models\'".$specificsModel; output  '\common\models\'ShoeBrand'
 $modelName = "\common\model".'\'.$specificsModel;
```

all not working any help on this thanks

Comment: have a look at [HereDoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$specModel = "ShoeBrand";
$modelName = "\\common\\models\\" . $specModel;

echo $modelName;
// will echo \common\models\ShoeBrand
```

You need to escape the backslash with a backslash. Same as you would to escape a `'` you would do `\'`. Here you have to do `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Try sprintf:

```
$x = sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    '\Common\Models\',
    $specModel
);
```

Because you use double-quotes, you need to escape the `\` using a doubled one: `\\`. Or just use single-quotes as often as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example for better understanding:

```
$PATH_ONE = "images"  
$PATH_TWO = "\\"    

$PATH = $PATH_ONE.$PATH_TWO
```

Remember that you have to escape character `\` (using the escape character `\`). String concatenation in PHP is performed using the `.` operator

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape the double quote:

`$modelName = "\common\models\\".$specModel;`

or escape the dollar sign putting the variable between the double quotes:

`$modelName = "\common\models\\$specModel";`

In the latter there is no concatenation, PHP will evaluate the variable if it is between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$specModel = 'ShoeBrand';
$modelName = '\\common\\models\\'.$specModel ;
```

Note that I changed the `"` to `'` and doubled the backslashes.

Answer (score -2):

You can try tidying-up your code. Try this:

```
  $specModel = "ShoeBrand";
  $modelName = "\common\models\" . $specModel;
```

Comment: it doesn't what this why i tried before posting the question, the last backslash will escape the last double quote and everything after it turns to a string..